# Python Shell Not Returning Anything

Tags: python

This is my code below that I believe should be working. When I call it, the python shell returns empty(blank) and just another Restart line pops up above. Wondering how to fix this?

Instructions for this function problem are the following:
Description: Write a function called animal_locator that takes in a dictionary
containing zoo locations as keys and their values being a list of tuples with the
specific animal and the population of that specific animal at that zoo. You should
return a dictionary containing the animals as keys and their values being a tuple
with their first element being an ordered list of all the zoo locations based on
how many animals are at each location (greatest to least) and the second element
being an integer of the total population of that specific animal.
You do not have to take in account case sensitivity.

```
def animal_locator(places):
newdict = {}
for city in places:
    numtup = len(places[city])
    num = 0
    while num < numtup:
        if places[city][num][0] not in newdict:
            newlist = []
            newtup = (places[city][num][1], city)
            newlist.append(newtup)
            for city1 in places:
                if city1 != city:
                    for tup in places[city1]:
                        if tup[0] == places[city][num][0]:
                            tupnew = (tup[1], city1)
                            newlist.append(tupnew)
            newlist.sort(reverse=True)
            count = 0
            newlist2 = []
            for tup in newlist:
                newlist2.append(tup[1])
                count += tup[0]
                newtup = (newlist2, count)
            newdict[places[city][num][0]] = newtup
    num += 1
return newdict

zoo_location1 = {'San Diego': [('lion', 4), ('tiger', 2), ('bear', 8)], 'Bronx': [('lion', 20), ('snake', 5), ('tiger', 1)], 'Atlanta': [('lion', 3), ('snake', 2), ('bee', 4500)], 'Orlando': [('bee', 234), ('tiger', 123)]}
animal_dict1 = animal_locator(zoo_location1)
print(animal_dict1)
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you were actually calling the function?

Answer (score 0):

I found out my num += 1 line needed to be indented by one tab and then it ran normally.